# All groups where underlying set has at most 4 elements

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, cayley-table

I have this homework problem.  It states:

By constructing the possible Cayley tables, list all groups where the underlying set has at most 4 elements, up to isomorphisms.  That is, no two groups in your list should be isomorphic.

I understand the basic use of Cayley tables in the sense that they are used to see what the operation on two of the elements becomes.  One group that I know that would fit this would be $\mathbb Z_4$.  I'm not sure how to list all of them and if there is a way to know if it will be isomorphic or not.

Comment: There are two groups of order $4$. Any group of order $4$ with an element of order $4$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$. See if you can identify what the other group must be by assuming that every element has order $2$ or $1$

Answer (score 2):

Either such a group has an element of order $4$, and it is cyclic, isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$. Or the maximal order of its elements is $2$, by *Lagrange's theorem*. Let $a$ be such an element,; the group must have another one, say $b$, since it has order $4$. Note we have $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{e\}$ and $ab=ba$, otherwise the group would have a fifth element.

Hence the group is  commutative, made up of $\{e, a, b, ab\}$ and it is the direct sum $\langle a\rangle\oplus\langle b\rangle$, isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ (*Klein's Vierergruppe*).